# Is it possible to enumerate identical instances of a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a set of models for keeping track of the signal flow in audio equipment. In order to properly model a mixer, for instance, I'd need to keep track of several identical inputs and outputs. For instance:

```
class signal(models.Model):
    # e.g., 1/4" mono cable
    name = models.CharField(max_Length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class component_type(models.Model):
    # e.g., mixer
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class input(models.Model):
    # e.g., a single channel on a mixer
    type = models.ForeignKey("signal")
    component_type = models.ForeignKey("component_type")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.component_type.name, self.type.name)
```

I can add a number of separate instances of a 1/4" mono jack for a mixer; that's no problem. What I'd like to do is auto-enumerate them, so that I can keep track of each individual channel. For instance, I'd like to have the first instance of a 1/4" mono input on a mixer to be represented as 'Mixer - 1/4" Mono 1' and the second instance to be 'Mixer - 1/4" 2', rather than having them both named 'Mixer - 1/4" Mono.'

I imagine this will require an additional field and hijacking the save method, but I'm not quite sure of how to go about it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be a good place to start:

```
from django.db.models import F

class Input(models.Model):
  type = models.ForeignKey("signal")
  component_type = models.ForeignKey("component_type")
  number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
      self.number = Input.objects.filter(component_type_id=self.component_type_id, type=self.type_id).count() + 1
    super(Input, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Input.objects.filter(component_type_id=self.component_type_id, type=self.type_id, number__gt=self.number).update(number=F('number')-1)
    super(Input, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

  def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.component_type, self.type, self.number)
```

We override the delete method to ensure that when an input gets deleted, all inputs with a higher number get a new correct number.

Some notes:

1) Please don't shoot if this doesn't work as is, the code is a sketch

2) I took the liberty of capitalizing model names, it's a standard practice which you could also adopt

3) In the delete method I use the update method to update the appropriate inputs at once without generating db overhead (one query). If this doesn't work exactly as is, you should still work on that direction

4) The presented unicode method does not explicitly use the component_type.name and type.name properties, but calls the corresponding unicode methods of each model (you might change the ComponentType's unicode in the future and Input will display the new version)

Comment: I'd figured out the save override, but the delete override is brilliant. Many thanks!

I also appreciate you correcting me on the model naming convention, too. I'd recently stopped doing it after running into errors from the _set names getting recased, but I don't want to upset any applecarts on any future collaborations. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome! Just one more note: the delete method does not get called when objects are massively deleted through the admin actions (on the Input's changelist view). As an alternative, you could try to use the post_delete signal instead, if that's aproblem for you. See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects for more information! Hope this helps